# CSS not rendered in Go server

Tags: html, css, go, server, localhost

I'm using `chi` as router.
My files tree is:

```
 -cmd
     - web
          - main.go and some other go files here*
          - static
                - assets
                - some html files here*
```

I have my routes set up like so:

```
mux := chi.NewRouter()

mux.Use(middleware.Logger)
mux.Use(middleware.SetHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"))

mux.Get("/about", app.serveFile)
mux.Get("/login", app.serveFile)
mux.Get("/register", app.serveFile)
mux.Get("/", app.serveFile)

fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./cmd/web/static/assets/"))
    mux.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fileServer))
```

Here is a snippet of my index.html file:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

Edit 1:
I'm using `make` as my build tool. Here is the rule to build and run the web:

```
build_web:
    @echo "building projectName web..."
    @go build -o ${BINARY_DIR}/${WEB_BINARY_NAME} ./cmd/web/*.go
    @echo "projectName web built"

run_web:
    @echo "running projectName web..."
    @./${BINARY_DIR}/${WEB_BINARY_NAME} -environment ${PREF_ENV} -port ${WEB_PORT}
```

Running the server on localhost, HTML pages are rendered but css rules are not applied. I checked the network tab of developer tools and it shows status code 200 for all assets (css/js/images). Same was reported through the middleware logger, a 200 status code for all files in the assets folder.
I've tried all stackoverflow answers I could stumble upon, still no luck.

Comment: What do you get if you do `curl <your_host>/assets/css/style.css`?

Comment: ... or what do you see in the browser when you enter <your_host>/assets/css/style.css in the browser address bar?

Comment: I got a redirect to my 404 page @mkopriva

Comment: @Ercross what directory are you running the process? I'm asking because you are using a relative http.Dir. Is the process' working directory the parent directory of `./cmd`? If not then that would be your problem.

Comment: @Ercross right above the `fileServer := ...` line do `fmt.Println(os.Getwd())` to confirm whether or not you are in `./cmd` parent directory.

Comment: @Ercross but if you are running the program from `./cmd/web/` where you have `main.go` then your process' working directory will also be `./cmd/web/` which is child of `./cmd/` and not its parent. Then you would use `http.Dir("./static/assets")` instead. It's best to use absolute paths though, read from a config file or env vars.

Comment: @mkopriva, os.Getwd printed `/home/ercross/go/src/projectName <nil>`. I have updated the question to show a snippet of my make file rules, build_web and run_web. From the make rules, you can see I'm building the binary file into a  ./bin directory

Comment: @Ercross If the process' working directory is the parent of `./cmd` then you need to figure out why your `http.FileServer` is unable to open the files. Does the process have enough permissions to be able read the files, or navigate the `./cmd/...` directory hierarchy? Perhaps try adding `f, err := os.Open("./cmd/web/static/assets/css/style.css")` to your program to figure out if it can find, open, and read the asset files.

Comment: @Ercross another thing you may try is: `http.StripPrefix("/assets", fileServer)` (prefix without the trailing slash)? I don't really think that that will fix your problem, but it won't hurt giving it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I eventually fixed this:
I entered `<address>/assets/css/style.css` in my browser and it returned 404 not found page.
Though it shows a status code 200 in the server log, but the file was not actually served. So I changed the path on my fileserver from `/assets/` to `/assets/*` (here: `mux.Handle("/assets/*", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fileServer))`) and it worked,
Thanks to @bayta-darrel and @mkopriva for their help

Comment: Still relevant today (Sep 3rd, 2023). Thank you! Please mark this as the answer.